# yeoman grunt Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.router

Tags: angularjs, bower, yeoman-generator-angular

I've problems using ui-router with
yeoman running grunt.

If I run

> grunt serve

the script works

with

> grunt

I've got:

```
Connected on socket um1BuGgogBUojHlvIawT with id 77936474
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Linux) Controller: MainCtrl should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope FAILED
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module browserApp due to:
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.router due to:
    Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.router' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/nomod?p0=ui.router
        at /home/whisher/browser/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
```

What's the problem !

:(

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "browser",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.2.16",
    "jquery": "~1.11.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.0.3",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.10.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.10"
},
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.15",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.15"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
 <!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/auth.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
    <body ng-app="browserApp">>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <h1><a data-ui-sref="home" class="navbar-brand">Test</a></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                <div data-ui-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="footer">
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>




      <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
      <!-- bower:js -->
      <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
      <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
      <!-- endbower -->
      <!-- endbuild -->
       <!-- Libs -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

      <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
      <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
      <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
      <script src="scripts/controllers/signin.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = {
                initialize: function() {
                    this.bindEvents();
                },
                bindEvents: function() {
                    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, true);
                },

                onDeviceReady: function() {
                    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
                        angular.bootstrap(document);
                    });
                }
            };
            app.initialize();
        </script>
      <!-- endbuild -->
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

'use strict';

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    //Fixing facebook bug with redirect
    if (window.location.hash === '#_=_') {
        window.location.hash = '#!';
    }
});

angular.module('browserApp', ['ui.router'])
    .run(['$rootScope','$log',function ($rootScope, $log) {
        $rootScope.$log = $log;
    }])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            // For unmatched routes:
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

            // states for my app
            $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
            .state('signin', {
                url: '/signin',
                templateUrl: 'views/signin.html',
                controller: 'SigninCtrl'
            });
        }
        ])
    .config(['$locationProvider',
        function($locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
        }
        ])
    .config(['$httpProvider',
        function($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
            delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        }
        ]);
```

controllers/main.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('browserApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl',['$scope' ,function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  }]);
```

Gruntfile.js

```
// Generated on 2014-05-03 using generator-angular 0.8.0
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Load grunt tasks automatically
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Project settings
        yeoman: {
            // configurable paths
            app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
            dist: 'dist'
        },

        // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
        watch: {
            bower: {
                files: ['bower.json'],
                tasks: ['bowerInstall']
            },
            js: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            jsTest: {
                files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
            },
            styles: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
                tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            gruntfile: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ]
            }
        },

        // The actual grunt server settings
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
                hostname: 'localhost',
                livereload: 35729
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                    ]
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    port: 9001,
                    base: [
                    '.tmp',
                    'test',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                    ]
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }
            }
        },

        // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },
            all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
            ],
            test: {
                options: {
                    jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
                },
                src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
            }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                    '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
        bowerInstall: {
            app: {
                src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
                ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
            }
        },

        // Renames files for browser caching purposes
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                flow: {
                    html: {
                        steps: {
                            js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
                            css: ['cssmin']
                        },
                        post: {}
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            options: {
                assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
            }
        },

        // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
        cssmin: {
            options: {
                root: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
            }
        },

        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },

        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },

        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },

        // ngmin tries to make the code safe for minification automatically by
        // using the Angular long form for dependency injection. It doesn't work on
        // things like resolve or inject so those have to be done manually.
        ngmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
                    src: '*.js',
                    dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Replace Google CDN references
        cdnify: {
            dist: {
                html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
            }
        },

        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                    '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    '*.html',
                    'views/{,*/}*.html',
                    'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                    'fonts/*'
                    ]
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/images',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
                    src: ['generated/*']
                }]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            }
        },

        // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
        concurrent: {
            server: [
            'copy:styles'
            ],
            test: [
            'copy:styles'
            ],
            dist: [
            'copy:styles',
            'imagemin',
            'svgmin'
            ]
        },

        // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
        // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
        // to use the Usemin blocks.
        // cssmin: {
        //   dist: {
        //     files: {
        //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
        //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        //         '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
        //       ]
        //     }
        //   }
        // },
        // uglify: {
        //   dist: {
        //     files: {
        //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
        //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
        //       ]
        //     }
        //   }
        // },
        // concat: {
        //   dist: {}
        // },

        // Test settings
        karma: {
            unit: {
                configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
                singleRun: true
            }
        }
    });


    grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'bowerInstall',
            'concurrent:server',
            'autoprefixer',
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
            ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
        grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', [
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:test',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:test',
        'karma'
        ]);

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'bowerInstall',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'concat',
        'ngmin',
        'copy:dist',
        'cdnify',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'rev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
        ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
        ]);
};
```

Comment: Can you show us your html and controller code?

Comment: Can you include the gruntfile?

Comment: I think ui-router library is not available. Please add this and check if works http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js

Comment: @TimCastelijns Castelijns I updated the post

Comment: I am having the same issue and have been working on this for 2 days.

Comment: I am having this issue as well - was hoping this post might lead to an answer. I'm able to run my app, but I get this error when running the tests

Answer (score 15):

What is failing is your default test generated by yeoman. By default yeoman adds angular-router as a routing tool. When you decide to use other tool, like ui-router you need to show it in your bower.json (as you already did) because grunt uses these dependencies to generate final script as well as index.html (adding required scripts).

There is another place you need to change for tests to pass. it is karma.conf.js file. There you need to add ui-router js file in "files" array

```
files: [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
  'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
  'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js', //remove this
  'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js', //add this
  'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js', 
  'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'test/mock/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js'
],
```

Comment: thanks for the reply I'm a little busy at moment when I've got free time I'll check it + 1 for the hint :)

Comment: Brilliant, for some reason I couldn't figure this out myself - this was the only place I found this information!

Comment: For me as well, it was the only place with I found info and also it has solved my issued working with dependencies on a yeoman fullstack project. It was not being generated by yo. Thx